# Why "with" here - My mother told me about these visits with Ruth and their worries

Tags: prepositions

I am reading The Longest Ride. The use of preposition in one sentence made me ask this question here.
The sentence is -

> My mother told me about these visits **with** Ruth and their worries.

The use of "with" here suggests that "my mother" visited somewhere with Ruth, right?

Now I am going to give the context quoting some lines from the previous texts -

> 'But I had also became friends with your mother in the year you (Ira) were gone (for schooling elsewhere). While my father was working, my mother and I would go to the shop. We would speak of Vienna and our old lives.....'
>   Ruth was saying this to Ira, looking back to their younger days. Now Ruth and Ira are married and too old.

Now I just want to know why "with" is used their in that sentence? It should have been "from" or "of", right?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase

> My mother told me about these visits with Ruth and their worries.

would not ordinarily mean that the mother used to go to some place together with Ruth, as I understand it. It would mean she visited Ruth's place and spent some time with Ruth there.

From the Cambridge Dictionary:

- [Visit with smb.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/visit-with-sb) - to spend time talking with or staying with someone you know: 'I was hoping *to visit with* Katie while I was in town'.

So preposition 'with' seems to be at its lawful place here. But I admit that it indeed seems ambiguous to me as a non-native speaker (I'm Russian), pointing at the possibility that the visits were indeed not to Ruth but carried out by the mother and Ruth to some unnamed place.

Your second quote, the bigger one, fails to clarify anything to me. I become tangled trying to unravel who visited whom and who said what to whom. (0:

P.S. I've found [a blog post on 'to visit with'.](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.ru/2012/10/visiting.html)

Comment: CopperKettle, in your link to the Cambridge Dictionary, I noticed that it has **US**, written under **visit with sb**. Using the word *with* like that, is a feature of American English. It is superfluous and not common, in England and the rest of the UK.